# Python Pandas Dataframe interpolation with strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I was wondering if Pandas Dataframe allows for interpolation for strings as well. (I have values working but not for strings).

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


s = pd.Series(["Blue", "Blue", np.nan, "Blue","Blue","Red"])
s = s.interpolate()

print(s)
```

Output:
Blue,
Blue,
NaN,
Blue,
Blue,
Red

Desired Output:
Blue,
Blue,
Blue,
Blue,
Blue,
Red

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use ffill.

```
s = s.ffill()
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case `s.interpolate(method='pad')` or `s.ffill()` will do just fine but you may compare and observe outputs of different techniques below:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([None, None, 'red', 'red', None, 'blue', None, None])

print(s.to_list())
print(s.bfill().tolist())
print(s.ffill().tolist())
print(s.bfill().ffill().tolist())
print(s.ffill().bfill().tolist())
print(s.interpolate(method='pad').tolist())
```

Output:

```
[None, None, 'red', 'red', None, 'blue', None, None]
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', None, None]
[None, None, 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
[None, None, 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 2):

no, you can't interpolate strings, but, it is possible to convert the strings to categories and then interpolate on that.

```
arr, cat = s.factorize()
s2 = pd.Series(arr).replace(-1, np.nan).interpolate()\
         .astype('category').cat.rename_categories(cat)\
         .astype('str')
```

Comment: great idea, but you need to use .interpolate(method='nearest') to avoid linear interpolation which will create new values of categories that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following will also work for strings:

`s = s.interpolate(method='pad')`

See the documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html.